# How to process data of small chunks in pandas?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am trying to process the data after using chunksize parameter. I am getting an error as it the iterator is not converting into a dataframe.

```
pdvs = dbu.readFromSQL("SELECT GOOGLE.* \
                           ,creation_time \
                        FROM [dbo].[DM_SOURCE_GOOGLE_DETAILS] AS GOOGLE\
                        JOIN \
                        ( \
                            SELECT place_id \
                                ,max(datetime) AS datetime \
                                , min(datetime) AS creation_time \
                            FROM [dbo].[DM_SOURCE_GOOGLE_DETAILS] \
                            GROUP BY place_id \
                        )AS date_updated \
                        ON GOOGLE.datetime = date_updated.datetime \
                            AND GOOGLE.place_id = date_updated.place_id", chunksize = 5
                       )

combined = pd.DataFrame(pdvs)
# get address
combined['valid'] = True
```

But the transformation is not working. I am getting the following error
 'generator' object does not support item assignment

Comment: i assume you use SQL Server (MSSQL) ? As the SQL tag is not meant for SQL Server (MSSQL) on this website but for ANSI/ISO SQL standards valid code which this code is clearly not.

Comment: yes that is the case, thanks for the clarification